# Trying to understand PSR-4 autoloading through a console app. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand PSR-4 autoloading by writing a very basic example app that runs on the console.

Here is my app's (directory) structure:

`app/
    -library/auth/Author/AuthorInterface.php
    -library/auth/Author/Author.php
    -library/auth/Authorize/
    -library/database/
    -vendor/composer/
    -vendor/autoload.php
    -composer.json
    -composer.lock
    -composer.phar
    -manager.php`

All I'm trying to do is run *manager.php* and have it echo a return statement from *Author.php*

**AuthorInterface.php:**

```
namespace Vee\Auth\Author;

interface AuthorInterface
{
    public function write();
}
```

**Author.php**

```
namespace Vee\Auth\Author;

class Author implements AuthorInterface
{
    function __construct()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public function write()
    {
        return "Hello.write";
    }
}
```

**manager.php:**

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Vee\Auth\Author;

echo new Author();
```

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vee\\": "library/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.21"
    }
}
```

And here's the error that I see when I try to run *manager.php*:

```
$ php manager.php 

Fatal error: Class 'Vee\Auth\Author' not found in /<path-to-app>/manager.php on line 7
```

I have already run:

```
$ php composer.phar update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I'm running PHP 5.5 on a Mac, if that makes any difference-

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.36 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2016 23:47:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: in psr4, namespace path should be same like map name path, including case

Comment: I made the change suggested by Vladimir so now namespace path is same like map name path but I'm seeing same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By psr-4 2.6

> All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.

and 3.3

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

Try renaming `auth` to `Auth`.

**Update:**

Just noticed that your use statement in manager.php is wrong.
Try:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Vee\Auth\Author\Author;

print (new Author())->write();
```

In addition you can't echo a class, even when you are returning string from constructor.

Comment: shouldnt it be auth/Author? Namespace should follow the structure like the folders right

Comment: changing to `Auth` didn't help - still seeing the same error.

Comment: @FTomex I've updated the answer. You need to reference fully qualified class name in your use statement.

Comment: That worked @VladimirCvetic! But now I'm confused. Why do I need to specify `...\Author\Author` twice? I have a file name ending in '.php' and matching the terminating class name: 'Author.php'

Comment: @FTomex In ``Author\Author`` first instance is part of class namespace (or dir structure) while last Author is class name.

Comment: Yes, I was able to infer that but my assumption (or misconception) was that every class should be in it's own directory and the directory should be named the same as the class name so that's why i was only referring to it by one `Author` instead of two. Because I thought both the Directory and the Class file combined to form the namespace fragment.

Comment: No class and directory name don't need to be the same and you can have a  bunch of classes in the same directory.